# R - Finding Survival Probability - Weibull AFT - Error: X and Y values differ?

Tags: r, regression, survival-analysis, weibull

I have data on bridge survivability: https://pastebin.com/1ryj68Bd.
I am new to R and Survival Analysis so this might sound basic but I have created a Weibull AFT model. I would like to predict the survival probability using the model for a specific set of variable values. How do I do that? To give you some context, here's the code:

```
weibul1=survival::survreg(survival::Surv(weibul$TIS,weibul$Survival) ~ weibul$ADT + weibul$NumberOfFreezeThawCycles + weibul$ADTT + weibul$NumberOfSnowfalls + weibul$Skew, weights = weibul$Quantity,  data = weibul[weibul$Age > 0,], dist = "weibull")
summary(weibul1) 

#plotting Weibull AFT; Gamma = 1/weibul1$Scale -- survreg gives log sigma and not sigma as output; Intercept = 1/weibul1$coefficients[1]
plot(weibul$Age,1-pweibull(weibul$Age,1/(weibul1$scale),exp(weibul1$coefficients[1])),xlab = 'Age', ylab='Survival Probability')
```

What I would like to do is given the value of ADT, ADTT, Age, etc. find the survival probability. I am using the `survival` package in R. So, I am using `predict` with the following code:

```
covariates = list(Age = 26.68, ADT=5267, ADTT=763.37, NumberOfSnowfalls=14.88 , NumberOfFreezeThawCycles=56.34, Skew = 13.39)
predict(weibul1, newdata=covariates,  type="quantile", p=(1:98)/100)

plot(predict(weibul1, newdata=covariates,type="quantile",p=seq(.01,.99,by=.01)),seq(.99,.01,by=-.01),col="green")
```

However, now I see an error: Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Any thoughts/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the length of x and y differ.

Try

```
length(predict(weibul1, newdata=covariates,  type="quantile", p=(1:1208)/100))
```

and

```
length((1:1208)/100)
```

They should be the same. Additionally, are you sure that x and y are correct? Maybe you want  them the other way round?

Comment: Do you mean that I want Survival Probability and this would give me Hazard?

Comment: No, I mean x and y. It makes sense for the predictions to be on the y axis right?